# Custom tweet button not working as expected

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter

At the very end of [this page](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button) titled Build Your Own Tweet Button, copying the code in my local wp works

code:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share?url=https%3A%2F%2Fdev.twitter.com%2Fpages%2Ftweet-button">Tweet</a>
```

Without all the css, this code produces a 'Tweet' link, when clicked shows (in a twitter box/page everything after the `?url=`

However, when I enter php in href, after `?url=` to show the post title, nothing shows. Not sure why this happens. Clues?

The code I used is:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share?url=<?php echo(the_title()); ?>">Tweet</a>
```

Comment: Why are you using the_title() function?

Comment: The only reason is because that is used to output the post title, so I figured I can use the same function to echo the post title in the tweet. Are you suggesting there's there's another function that can be used? Please share.

Comment: Using `<?php echo get_the_title($ID); ?>` didn't help either. Not sure what @Devon is suggesting. Is there any other function that can or should be used?

Comment: According to https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button, url= is supposed to be the URL of the page, not the page title.  I'm not too familiar with WP, so I'm not sure what function you should use.  What does the source of the HTML show?  Right click with your browser and go to view source.  I'm assuming the page title is conflicting with the HTML.

Comment: @Devon what you said is true, however: 1. I am talking (and referred to) about the Build Your Own Tweet Button, which if you noticed clearly says JavaScript Interfaces for Twitter for Websites are not available for custom Tweet Buttons. 2. The URL you are mentioning is mentioned at the top of the page where twitter buttons are used, in which case the javascript parameters like URL work. 3. A URL is a URL be it for the page, a single post page, a title, etc., twitter can't make the difference, it's just a link.

Comment: @OP: If you are to use the_title(), try using something like: urlencode(the_title()) to replace any conflicting HTML.  I put htmlentities, I meant urlencode for this example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the_title() is producing conflicting HTML with the link.  Possibly:

```
urlencode(the_title())
```

Will fix the problem.

Comment: It should look like: `https://twitter.com/share?url=Hello+world%21` with urlencode() but there doesn't seem to be any issue with how it is written right there HTML-wise.  The problem must be elsewhere.